# try block is not getting executed

Tags: python, statsmodels, try-except

This is my code:

```
p = range(0,3)
q = range(0,3)
d = range(0,3)
s = range(30,31)
P =range(0,1)
D = range(1,2)
Q = range(0,1)
lowest_aic= None
lowest_parm = None
lowest_param_seasonal = None
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = list(itertools.product(P,D,Q,s))
for param in pdq:
  for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
    try:
      mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data,order=param,seasonal_order=param_seasonal)
      results = mod.fit()

      current_aic = results.aic

      if (lowest_aic == None):
        lowest_aic = results.aic

      if (current_aic <= lowest_aic):
        lowest_aic = current_aic
        lowest_parm = param
        lowest_param_seasonal = param_seasonal
        #print('SARIMA{}x{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        print('SARIMA{},{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
    except:
      continue


  print('SARIMA{}x{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
  syhat_sar_c = results.predict(len(df), len(df)+6, typ='levels',dynamic=False)
  print(np.array(syhat_sar))
```

I am trying to implement a grid search for my SARIMA model.
I would like to know why try block is not getting executed, because of which it is throwing, UnboundLocal error.

It would be great if the explanation would be detailed.

This is the traceback I am getting when I run this code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2669d247586e> in <module>()
     35 
     36 
---> 37   print('SARIMA{}x{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
     38   syhat_sar_c = results.predict(len(df), len(df)+6, typ='levels',dynamic=False)
     39   print(np.array(syhat_sar))

NameError: name 'results' is not defined
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: If ```try``` is not executed is probably because there is an error in your try block, I suggest to print the exception from the ```except``` block using: ```except Exception as e: print(e)```

Comment: In the `except` block, at least print the exception.  Don't just continue.

Comment: If the `sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX()` or `mod.fit()` functions throw an error, then the local variable `results` is never created.

Comment: You really should limit the size of the code in the `try` block. Only include in it code that you know may cause exceptions. In your case, I would guess that these are just the first two statements in the block (maybe even just the second). Putting many statements in a `try` block masks multiple potential exceptions that you did not mean to catch.

Comment: I did following checks: 1.  Checked `pdq` and `seasonal_pdq` it prints the combination 2.  I tried printing some random stuff in except it always prints the statement inside except block.

Comment: @DavidBuck `UnboundLocalError: variable results has been referenced before it is assigned` I get this as traceback

Comment: @AmitaiIrron Should I only use SARIMA finction and fit method inside try block and rest outside?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes,this is the probably error,I am assigning a tuple for Order and Seasonal Order.

Comment: One of the strange fact I would like to share is that initially when I tried implementing this as a function it was working property and I did get intended result. I tried calling this code inside a function and it caused error.

Comment: That's not "The full traceback". That's just the error message. Please post the whole thing, and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61600867/edit) your question to add it, please don't post it as a comment.

Comment: @DavidBuck I have updated  the question with  traceback

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities:

1. `pdq` is empty, so the outer `for` loop exits immediately and the `try` is never executed.
2. `seasonal_pdq` is empty, so the inner `for` loop exits immediately and the `try` is never executed.
3. The `try` is executed, but it terminates before the variable you're depending on has been bound.

The rudimentary debugging techniques you could use to narrow this down would be:

1. Print `pdq` to make sure it's not empty.
2. Print `seasonal_pdq` to make sure it's not empty.
3. Change the `continue` to a `raise` so that the exception is raised instead of ignored.  That way you can see what it is and exactly what line it came from.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying I have check the for loops by printing it's values,so PDQ,seasonal_pdq is not empty. In a seperate code base when I ran except statement with print statement,it was skipping try and went to except part.

Comment: If you let the exception raise, it will stop your program and print a callstack that shows you why it's raising and exactly what line.  As soon as the `try` block hits that exception, it immediately stops and goes directly to the `except`.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you with results.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 30, in <module>
    print('SARIMA{},{} - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
NameError: name 'results' is not defined`
this is the result

Comment: Did you replace the `continue` with a `raise` like I suggested?  If so, the program should stop before it even gets to that point (and the error it prints will tell you exactly what's wrong).

Comment: This is the error I found replacing `continue`  with a ` raise`

Comment: So it's raising *inside* the loop, on a line after the one where you've defined `results`, and saying that `results` doesn't exist?  Are you sure nothing else has changed in the code?